# Date Validation in Shell Script [Unix]

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix

I'm trying to create a script that can validate the date parameter in shell script,

```
pDate=06/04/2015 (mm/dd/yyyy)
vDate=$(echo $pDate | awk  -F '/' '{ print ($1 <= 12 && $2 <= 31 && match($3, /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/)) ? 1 : 0 }')
```

My problem is the script always accepts day 31.

Comment: Because you tell it too.  `$2 <= 31`.  Are you implying you need to verify the correct days in each month?  (i.e. Jan == 31, Feb == 28)

Comment: You don't want to do this by hand and have to deal with leap years and whatnot. Use tools that are battle-tested.